# Session destroyed and abandoned but performance monitor still shows session count

Tags: .net, session, asp.net-4.0, monitor

This is the case. I used Performance Monitor, add counter for **Session Active** for **ASP.Net Apps v4.xx.xx** I have a web-based application that uses cookieless session.

I opened the application with a web-browser. The session count in Performance Monitor shows 1. I opened another and count increases. When I closed one, the count does not drop until session timeout (I believe, as the count decreases after the timeout value).

I tried log in 2 times, and log out, as well. The session count did not drop after log out.

Can anyone explain why this happens, and if there is a good (and trusted) tool that I can use to monitor session alive or destroyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions are nothing to do with authentication. Log out invalidates your cookie but your session will live until the session timeout. If you want to abandon the session on log out, you will need to add your own code to call `Session.Abandon();`

Comment: In that case, the session would always be there until timeout? So for security, we need to clear the information in the Sessions when logging out? I have called Session.Abandon() in the code, right after Session.Remove(), during log out.

Comment: Yes, session lives until timeout, it's a common scenario to have public pages for non-members that still require state. If you feel you have sensitive information in the session you should use HTTPS. If destroying the session on logout suites your business case, it will certainly remove some memory pressure on the server.